# Powershell regex for a tricky link selection

Tags: regex, powershell

A long string contains links of the following type: http://<something>/yyy<one character>.jpg Examples: http://aaa/bb/yyy1.jpg http://c/d/e/f/g/h/yyyz.jpg

Let's call this relevant links. The string can contain zero, one or more of such relevant links. The string can also contain other links that are irrelevant.

The goal is to select the first relevant link in the string.

I can do this with a trick, but can this be done with just one regex and one match?

P.S. Here is the trick I currently use:

```
$regex='(^.*)(http://.*yyy..JPG)' 
$TMP=$S
$firstmatch=''
while ($TMP -match $regex)
{
 $TMP=$Matches[1]
 $firstmatch=$Matches[2]
} 
$link=$firstmatch
```

Comment: Welcome to SO... its not a site for doing your homework. Post your code to show your effort in solving this which convince others to help you out. Please finish the tour as well. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Hi, Mr. Admonition. Here is my code:
$TMP=$R2

$regex='(^.*)(http{0,1}://.*'+'yyy..JPG)' 

 $firstmatch=''

 while ($TMP -match $regex)

 {

  $TMP=$Matches[1]

  $firstmatch=$Matches[2]

 } 

 $link=$firstmatch

Comment: Lol.. no.. review is done to increase quality of the question and help new users to adapt to SO rules gently. So.. add your commented code to your question by editing it. NP with doing that and it improves readability.

Comment: Good to see the improvement. Now hope someone is able to help you out. Enjoy your stay at SO ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the regex pattern non-greedy. This way it only matches the minimum.

```
' http://aaa/zzz.jpg http://aaa/zzz.jpg http://bbb.yyy1.jpg'  -match '\s(http://[\S]*?yyy.\.JPG)' 
$Matches[1]
```

Result:

```
True
http://bbb.yyy1.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, Olaf, but your solution doesn't work for string 'h t t p ://aaa/zzz.jpg h t t p ://bbb.yyy1.jpg', returns the whole string.

Comment: Of course not. The string in your original post did not have spaces in between the "http". If you change the string you have to change the pattern as well.

Comment: I added spaces because the site does not show text with "http" correctly. Please remove them. The solution will still not work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce  - it works on my systems just like I posted it. `'http://aaa/bb/yyy1.jpg http://c/d/e/f/g/h/yyyz.jpg' -match 'http://.*?yyy.\.JPG'`. If you like to post code in comments you have to enclose it in backticks.

Comment: Ah ... now I see ... you used another string. I updated the code in my answer. Try now.

Comment: Thanks, Olaf. This works with my previous example, but doesn't work if I add a leading space. It does not work fo this string either: `http://aaa/zzz.jpg http://aaa/zzz.jpg http://bbb.yyy1.jpg`

Comment: If you change the conditions again and again and again you will never have a reasonable result. From a certain point you are expected to do your own research and change your code accordingly to your needs. I changed the answer again to reflect your new requisition. It would be fair from you when accept my answer once upon a time.